# Possible Memory Leak in Jersey 2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, jersey-2.0, java-mission-control

I had recently migrated my REST APIs from Jersey 1 to Jersey 2 (2.22.1 to be exact). The application is running as a spring boot app. The application receives a fairly large amount of traffic.
I profiled the application using JMC(Java Mission Control) and noticed large amount of memory consumed by Annotations (`getEntityAnnotations()`).  More details in the jms screenshot:

[image: jms screenshot]

From the screenshot you can see that 312 `Annotation[]` objects hold 1.55 GB of memory (~5 MB per array). I had break point in the `getEntityAnnotations()` method and observed that the `Annotation[]` contains only 3 annotations (HTTP Method, Path and Consumes). The Annotation objects have only a few fields. I am not able to explain the reason for the large size of the fields. More details in debugger screenshot:

[image: debugger screenshot]

Has anyone encountered a similar issues?

Additionally from the jms screenshot we can observe that half of the memory is from `Arrays.copyOf`. This is because the `getEntityAnnotations()` method in the `OutboundMessageContext` class clones the `entityAnnotations` array. This particular implementation has been added in jersey 2.5 as a part of the ticket [JERSEY-2072](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2072).

I am using Java 1.8.0_60 and spring boot 1.3.2.RELEASE.
Please let me know if you need any additional details about the application or the environment